# Traversing through all possible elements in the data structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I'm stuck with algorithmic problem for several days and any help is appreciated here.

Let's say that I have some modules in my app which can call other modules (as submodules). Something like blocks in Matlab Simulink. Also modules could call each one forming a loop.

For the sake of simplicity I've made a schema how that could look like.

[image]

In admin panel administrator can activate or deactivate some of these modules. For activation it is quite easy. Only one chain must be checked. But for deactivation it is tricky. We cannot just deactivate it because it might be used by some other module(s). That's why all possible cases must be checked.
Also all submodules of that one must be deactivated (and checked if used by other modules).

For example, let's say that I want to deactivate X (and it's submodules A-B-C-E)

X is inside D:

```
D - X
```

and inside:

```
Z - N
```

which calls

```
D - X
```

Also X calls the whole chain which should be deactivated:

```
X - A - B - C - E
```

So once again, this whole chain (X-A-B-C-E) has to be deactivated but we must check if X-A-B-C-E is used somewhere else first.

I work in C++ but any pseudocode would be helpful.

What I've tried so far is setting first X-A-B-C-E in a Map.. Then going for all chains and cancel the ones in my initial Map. The ones which are left are safe to deactivate. But it doesn't work.

Also tried to parse this as Linked lists... But also there I don't know where to start and how to go through all possible combinations.

Like I said, it's the tricky one and any tip is helpful.

Comment: What happens if a module in the middle of a chain is disabled? Will it be skipped and the next continues, or will the chain be terminated prematurely?

Comment: If you have less than about 1000 modules, you could probably do it the obvious  brute-force way.

Comment: One module can be checked at a time (with it's submodules). So if it is in the middle then that element would need to be disabled and checked if there are its children which are used somewhere else. If any is used, then we cannot disable it.

Comment: Can you clarify the rules? If I disable the element in the middle of the chain (or beginning, or end), the whole chain needs to be disabled? (e.g. if I disable X, I also need to disable Z and N and D?) And then it goes recursively? So in this example I need to disable XABDCE DX ZNDX, and therefore also BCE YMCE because these chains have "E"?

Comment: @user253751 even brute-force would be good start here :D ...

Comment: @pptaszni you need to look at this from top to bottom. If you need to disable X then you have to check for X-A-B. B contains C-E so in the end it is X-A-B-C-E ... If it is the element in the middle. Like B. Then you need to check for C-E which are again used in Y-M-C-E :D ... And also check if any of these elements are used somewhere else too. So the question is, how to know if any element is used somewhere. For any of them it must  be check through all elements.

Comment: So you only have to check "down" the chains, never "up"?

Comment: @Galik yes only "down", but for each chain. Again example. To disable D we need to look down for its children. It is X in this case. And X calls X-A-B-C-E . So the whole chain D-X-A-B-C-E has to be checked and disabled.

Comment: So what you're actually trying to find out is if you can disable a given module M, or if it has to stay active?

Comment: @Timo First I need to check if it is safe to disable. Then disable M with its children.

Comment: But isn't disabling a module only possible if it isn't used anywhere else? So disabling a module should only disable the one chain where the first module is your target M?

Comment: True. That is the point. But how to know if it is used anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the straightforward brute-force approach:

1. Make a list of modules you are going to disable.
2. Make a list of modules you have already looked at.
3. Add X to the list of modules you're going to disable.
4. Find a module you're going to disable that you haven't already looked at. Call it M.
5. Add M to the list of modules you've already looked at.
6. Identify the other modules that have to be disabled if M is disabled. Add all of them to the list of modules you are going to disable, unless they're already in the list.
7. Repeat steps 4-6 until there are no modules you haven't looked at yet.

But note that two lists might not be the best data structure here. It is probably more efficient to have a boolean flag in each module indicating whether you've looked at it. I'm just illustrating the general idea, ignoring such details.

If this looks like a breadth-first search, that's because it is.

Comment: Thanks! It is actually a BFS.. This example solved my problem. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/ ... Thanks a lot!